# tuples python pop and append

Tags: python, tuples, extend

```
t2=("A","B","Hello") 
alist=["Barney",["Wilma"]] 
alist.append(t2)

print(alist.pop(1).extend(t2)) 
print(alist) 
print((alist[1][2].upper())) 
print(alist)
```

Hi guys. I just had a qs regarding tuples as I am new to python.

1. why does  `print(alist.pop(1).extend(t2))` give NONE on execution?
2. Why does `print(a list)` below that give `['Barney', ('A', 'B', 'Hello')]` and not open tuple inside list as the function used is extend and not append?

   ```
   alist=["Hello"] 
   t1=(1,2,[3,4],5,6)
   t1[2].append(alist) 
   print(t1) 
   t1[2].pop().append(t1) 
   print(a list)
   ```

qs- Why does print(a list) in the end print `['Hello', (1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6)]`? is it because the thing that is pooled in the previous sentence i.e. Hello is alist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `list.extend` extends the list in place (see the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) , and thus returns none. Rather than having a new variable with the extended list, your list with the new items is still called `alist`
2. alist prints `['Barney', ('A', 'B', 'Hello')]`, because that's what you've asked it to do. 
   Step by step,

`t2=("A","B","Hello")`

```
alist=["Barney",["Wilma"]] 

alist.append(t2) # ['Barney', ['Wilma'], ('A', 'B', 'Hello')]

pop1 = alist.pop(1) # ['Wilma']
extend1 = pop1.extend(t2) #extend1 = None, pop1 = ['Wilma', 'A', 'B', 'Hello']
print(alist.pop(1).extend(t2)) # None
print(alist) #you've popped wilma, so the rest remains:   ['Barney', ('A', 'B', 'Hello')]
```

As for third, this should be exactly the behavior you expect. First, you pop `hello` from `alist`, then you append all of `t1` to the thing you just popped, namely `hello`. So, ['Hello', (1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6)] should be what you expected to get. Did you expect something different?

`print(alist)` on the last line prints `['Hello', (1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6)]`, because when you run `t1[2].pop()`, what you get is a a reference to alist in particular, not an arbitrary list element. So then, the `append(t1)` appends `t1` to the actual alist, which you then print.

Comment: @JoanSmith I am trying to understand what you said. So wouldn't taking out ['wilma'] and extending t2=("A","B","Hello")  give ['wilma',"A","B","Hello"], instead of having t1 inside  ()?

Comment: @vishal check the update, that might make it clearer.

Comment: absolutely clear! thanks! but by going with that concept how is alist in 2nd qs ['Hello', (1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6)]?

Comment: @vishal Edited to answer

Answer (score 1):

I'll try answering your first 2 questions:

1. `alist.pop(1).extend(t2)` works like this:

   -> `alist.pop(1)` returns `["Wilma"]` and `alist` becomes `['Barney', ('A', 'B', 'Hello')]`

   -> `["Wilma"].extend(t2)` returns None and only extends the temporary list without modifying `alist`
2. `print(alist)` shows `['Barney', ('A', 'B', 'Hello')]` because earlier you had executed `alist.append(t2)`

Comment: Nice and concise. Minor correction: after the `pop`, `alist` becomes `['Barney', ('A', 'B', 'Hello')]`, since that's after the `append`

Answer (score 0):

Lets see what your code does here:

After the third line, `alist.append(t2)`, `alist` is `["Barney",["Wilma"], ("A","B","Hello")]`. Now you `pop` (remove) `["Wilma"]` from the list, and extend *that list* with the tuple `t2`. That list would then be `["Wilma","A","B","Hello"]`, but it's bound to no variable, and since `extend` is in-place the result of that operation is `None`, which is printed. And since the Wilma-sublist (including its extension) got removed from the list, `alist` is now `["Barney", ("A","B","Hello")]`.

So to answer your questions in short:

1. Because the return value of `extend` is `None`
2. Because `extend` was applied to the return value of `pop`, not to `alist`, but the tuple was `append`ed to `alist` earlier in the code.